# Most polarizable solid under standard conditions?

Tags: polarization

I'm trying to figure out what the most polarizable solid that can be used at standard conditions is.

1. Wikipedia says alkanes are the most polarizable materials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability
2. I also found this table of the polarizability of elements: http://ctcp.massey.ac.nz/2018Tablepol.pdf

From 1) I'd hypothesize parafin wax?

From 2) I'd hypothesize an aqueous gel (OK, technically not a solid, but still useful) spiked with an iodine salt?

Comment: Are you looking for materials with the highest epsilon_r? That's probably materials that are being used to make ceramic capacitors like barium titanate.

Comment: @FlatterMann I think the symbol for polarizability is alpha.

Comment: See Clausius-Mossoti for the translation between the two quantities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Mossotti_relation